# How to decrypt Laravel Encrypter in Javascript client?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, encryption, aes

I have encrypted the response from the server using Laravel encrypter.

I'm using Laravel 5.8

```php
use Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter;
....
$key = "ls1KlnDpyl2ZJT0vdNX1tNygAftBlgah";
$value = "secret";
$encrypter = new Encrypter($key, 'AES-256-CBC');
$encrypt = $encrypter->encryptString($value);
return response()->json([
           'payload' => $encrypt
       ], 200);
```

My question is, how to decrypt it in javascript client ? or how to encrypt decrypt in javascript if i want to use Laravel encrypter for read it.

Comment: I don't think that's going to be possible. You should make a new function or file, and use Ajax to make a request and retrieve the unencrypted content. Or why do you need to encrypt in laravel and decrypt in JS?

Comment: To decrypt, you also need to place the secret key on the client. This would destroy the security and the purpose of the encryption.

Comment: @odan Not unless you have the user enter the secret key client side & it never goes over the wire. Not ideal but not a major flaw.

Comment: Thank you for commented, for decrypt i've successfully. I can't encrypt in JavaScript with the standard Laravel encrypter

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to decrypt it. **But without validation**

Example code :

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-base64@2.5.1/base64.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.2/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>

function decrypt(){

  // key set on the server when encrypt using Laravel encrypter
  var key = "ls1KlnDpyl2ZJT0vdNX1tNygAftBlgah";

  // response from server
  var encrypted = "eyJpdiI6IjN2UmswOFVOd0lncHh4cCszbThnc1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMllmZ0dHTCtmejg0VFV1dVlFZVNhQT09IiwibWFjIjoiYzliODBkYTUzMDlmODEwMjJlY2Y2ZDhmN2UwM2NkN2FjYTc3OThjOTA3NTAyYTIxMDM3MjE5NDY2NTlhY2RjMSJ9";

  var encrypted_json  = JSON.parse(Base64.decode(encrypted));

  // {"iv":"3vRk08UNwIgpxxp+3m8gsQ==","value":"2YfgGGL+fz84TUuuYEeSaA==","mac":"c9b80da5309f81022ecf6d8f7e03cd7aca7798c907502a2103721946659acdc1"}

  var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_json.value, CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(Base64.encode(key)),{
                     iv: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encrypted_json.iv),
                     mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
                  });
  console.log('decripted : ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));

}


</script>
```

And now, how to encrypt in javascript and i can read it in server with Laravel encrypter ?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question. Don't hide questions in your answer

Answer (score 1):

You should not use Laravel APP_KEY(var key in your case) on the frontend side. NEVER! Laravel uses APP_KEY to encrypt everything including cookies (Session cookie and csrf cookie).

Your application could be hacked if it's in your HTML code! To answer your question a bit: use Crypt::decrypt($encrypted) on the server-side of your application (within Laravel).